# Updatepanel resets progress bar to zero while refreshing

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, updatepanel

This is just the sample code which I am trying to achieve and it cannot be performed by Javascript.

Used an Updatepanel and trying to update the progress bar that it shows the progress while function is in execution

But when doing this, updatepanel starts from zero when it is refreshed

(It's not smooth continuous transition, rather it starts from zero and reaches to specified point everytime when timer-tick event occurs)

ASPX

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="Timer1" Interval="1000" Enabled="False" 
        ontick="Timer1_Tick" />
    <br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
            <br />
            <br />

           <div id="div3" runat="server" class="progress progress-danger progress-striped progress progress_sm active " style="width: 100%;">
                 <div id="e3" class="bar" runat="server" role="progressbar">
                 </div>
           </div>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

JavaScript

```
var percentage;
function updateProgress2(percentage) {
        var $bar1 = $("#e3");
        //var $bar1 = $('.bar');
        var pp = percentage + "%";
        $bar1.width(pp);
        $bar1.text(pp + "%");
}
```

C#

```
static int count2, i;
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i=0;
        count2=20;
        Button1.Enabled = false;
        Timer1.Enabled = true;

    }

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "lol", "updateProgress2('" + count2 + "')", true);

        i++;
        count2 += 10;
        if (count2 == 90)
        {
            Timer1.Enabled = false;
            Button1.Enabled = true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i want see your 'count2' property.

i can use this 'count2' property with session.

this code work correctly.

```
private int count2
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["count2"] == null)
            Session["count2"] = 0;

        return int.Parse(Session["count2"].ToString());
    }
    set
    {
        Session["count2"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: No property....Just the declaration. Check C# code again. I've updated it.

Comment: umm. i am sorry. this code work in my computer. i don't know problem. only diffrent 'count2' your code.